# Am I checking for a white pixel correctly?

Tags: ros, gazebo

I am currently going through all the pixels in an image to determine what is a white pixel. I then have to decide where to drive the bot. I am also using [sensor_msgs/Image.msg](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) that I get from the `/camera/rgb/image_raw` channel.

However, I can't seem to locate any white image with the code but the `RGBa` values I set in my model in `gazebo` all have value `1` as shown in the image below the code .

I logged all my values(more than once) with `ROS_INFO_STREAM` but no values are `255`, let alone `3` consecutive ones.

```
void process_image_callback(const sensor_msgs::Image img)
{
  const int white_pixel = 255;

  const int image_slice_width = img.step / 3;

  int j = 0;
  bool found = false;

  for (int i = 0; not found and i < img.height; i++) 
  {
    for (j; j < img.step-3; j += 3)
    {
      if (img.data[i*img.step + j] == white_pixel)
      {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("img.data[i*img.step + (j + 0)]" + std::to_string(img.data[i*img.step + (j + 0)]));
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("img.data[i*img.step + (j + 1)]" + std::to_string(img.data[i*img.step + (j + 1)]));
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("img.data[i*img.step + (j + 2)]" + std::to_string(img.data[i*img.step + (j + 2)]));
      }
      // img.data only has one index
      if (img.data[i*img.step +  j     ] == white_pixel and
          img.data[i*img.step + (j + 1)] == white_pixel and
          img.data[i*img.step + (j + 2)] == white_pixel)
      {
          found = true;
          break;
      }
    }
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("End of j loop");
  }

  if (found)
  {
    // go left, forward or right
  }
  else
  {
    // no white pixel seen so stop the bot
  }
}
```

[image: gazebo RGBA settings]

Comment: why do you expect a white pixel to have an exact value of 255?

Comment: It has the highest possible value of red, green and blue was my thinking since I set it. Why would it not have that? Oh, I missing the image to show my settings.

Comment: I've worked on this same exercise before and didn't need nested for loops. You could borrow that part from mine and see if any pixels = 255 are found. If yes, then there's an issue with your nested for presumably. Here's my code: https://github.com/abhishek47kashyap/udacity-robotics-software-engineer/blob/b305cce6cb82322362a5204e2f3fc8d5c16bd692/Project2/ball_chaser/src/process_image.cpp#L44

Comment: I suggest you require pixel intensities to be above some specified value instead exactly the value. If the RGB values are all 254, is that not close enough?

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> the `RGBa` values I set in my model in `gazebo` all have value `1`

and you also said:

> but no values are `255`

Which I would expect is correct, because you just said you set them all to 1. Did you mean to scale them from 1 to 255 at some point? Casting `1.0` from `float` to `uint8` will give you `1`, not `255`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a bug in your code as pointed to by @MorganStark47 above [in the comment](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/20664/am-i-checking-for-a-white-pixel-correctly#comment33952_20664)

You may also want to use `Gazebo/White` as the material versus `Gazebo/Grey` to get the full brightness. I think the settings your adjusting effect how it interacts with different light sources and may not fully override the texture which a grey will take off some of the brightness.

There's a list here: http://wiki.ros.org/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/ListOfMaterials